# Vinculate Schemas on MongoDB using Express and mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to link my schemas within my "Movie" entity so that I can have my information both in the "Movie" entity and in the others, they are:

- Category
- Actor
- director
- Studio

for now I'm testing categories

My code is the following:

*controllers/movie.js*

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
    const content = req.body;

    const category = await Category.findById(content._id);
    const actor = await Actor.findById(content._id);
    const director = await Director.findById(content._id);
    const studio = await Studio.findById(content._id);
    
    const newMovie = new Movie({
        ...content,
        category,
        actor,
        director,
        studio
    });

    const savedMovie = await newMovie.save();

    category.movies = [...category.movies, savedMovie._id];
    await category.save();
    actor.movies = [...actor.movies, savedMovie._id];
    await actor.save();
    director.movies = [...director.movies, savedMovie._id];
    await director.save();
    studio.movies = [...studio.movies, savedMovie._id];
    await studio.save();

    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Movie created successfully',
        movie: savedMovie
    });
};
```

*models/movie.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema; 

const movieSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    year: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    duration: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    score: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    director: [{
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Director",
    }],
    actor: [{
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Actor",
    }],
    studio: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Studio",
    },
    poster: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    trailer: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema);
```

*models/category.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const {ObjectId} = Schema;
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    movies: [
      {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Movie",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

*controllers/category.js*

```
const Category = require('../models/category');

const create = async (req, res) => {
    const category = Category(req.body);
    
    res.status(201).json(
        await category
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Category created successfully',
                category: result
            });
        })
    );
};
```

Next I will show the error when making my request

**Request**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/movies HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
        "title": "The Matrix",
        "year": 1999,
        "duration": "136 min",
        "rating": "R",
        "score": "8.7",
        "categoryId": "62650106b643152d5fc5204e",
        "description": "A computer hacker learns from mysterious rebels about the true nature of his reality and his role in the war against its controllers.",
        "directorId": ["626502e956cd00fe36692bf9"],
        "actorId": ["626501fc56cd00fe36692bf2"],
        "studioId": "626502ac56cd00fe36692bf7",
        "poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzQzOTk3OTAtNDQ0Zi00ZTVkLWI0MTEtMDllZjNkYzNjNTc4L2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "trailer": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/m8e-FF8MsqU"
}
```

**Response**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'movies' of null
> at create (C:\Users\Ernesto\Desktop\streaming-backend\src\controllers\movie.js:26:36)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Comment: You schema for `Movie` has an _array_ named `category` but your request has a _single_ element named `categoryId`. That does not match.

Comment: I already changed array for a single element, but it keeps showing me the previous error.

Comment: Please update the question to reflect your change. Have you also aligned the names (`category` vs. `categoryId`)?

Comment: yes, and i updated my question

Comment: `newMovie = new Movie({content, ...})` seems wrong because a `Movie` has no property `content`. Did you mean `newMovie = new Movie({...content, ...})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the errors say it all.
Here is one of those `"message": "Path 'trailer' is required."`This means the movie doesn't have this attribute. Let's see why.

This is the code that you used to save a movie:

```
const newMovie = new Movie({
        content,
        category: category._id,
        actor: actor._id,
        director: director._id,
        studio: studio._id
    });             
    
    
    try {
        const result = await newMovie.save();
```

No sign of `trailer`, so the only place to look for is the `content`. You are assigning `content = Movie(req.body)` which eventually turns `content` into an object. So I will rewrite the data you pass to the constructor:

```
const content = {the properties in here}
const newMovie = new Movie({
        {the properties in here} //I replace the value of `content` here
    });
```

I hope you see the problem now. If not, reveal the answer below:

> Use `...content` in instead of just `content`

Comment: i updated the question with other error, thanks for follow my problem

Comment: Each topic is a question, you can't just add up like that. Please close this one and open a new one for new problem. And more important, make sure you spend time reading and understanding the error message, do your homework first. Then explain what have you done so far in the question, this shows that your effort in resolving the issue